# Doctrine 2 - Join data wthout relation

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine, many-to-many, relation

i have this structure in my basic model:

```
class Value extends ...
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    ...
}
```

This model cant be extended from my site, but i need to add a self-referencing ManyToMany relation for reading associated data.

So i created this new model:

```
class ValueGrid extends ...
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $parentValueId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parentValueID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $parentValueId;

    /**
     * @var integer $childValueId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="childValueID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $childValueId;

    ...
}
```

When i read data from "Value", i do it like this:

```
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select(array('value'))
        ->from('Value', 'value');

// Next i need to simulate the relation
$builder->addSelect(['valuegrid']);
$builder->leftJoin('ValueGrid', 'valuegrid', 'WITH', 'value.id = valuegrid.parentValueId');
```

It gives this output:

```
{"id":1,"value":"a"},
null,
{"id":2,"value":"b"},
null,
{"id":3,"value":"c"},
{"id":1,"parentValueId":1,"childValueId":2},
{"id":4,"value":"d"},
null,
{"id":5,"value":"e"},
null
```

But it should be this format:

```
{"id":1,"value":"a", "valuegrid":null},
{"id":2,"value":"b", "valuegrid":null},
{"id":3,"value":"c", "valuegrid":{"id":1,"parentValueId":1,"childValueId":2}},
{"id":4,"value":"d", "valuegrid":null},
{"id":5,"value":"e", "valuegrid":null},
```

Anyone has some suggestions?

I really dont know why my approach does not work..

Thansk and Greetings!

Comment: Stupid question: why can't you modify the entity?

Comment: because i am working on a Content Management System, where i can only add or remove columns, but not add or remove relations.. you get my point?

Comment: Ok ... that just does not make any sense. Relations are, pretty much, just extra columns ... and what does making a CMS have to do with it. :/

Anyway, as far as your problem: it seem slike you're using "leftJoin" in a DQL like you would in an SQL, which is not correct and in a DQL it works quite a bit differently.